# context.$implicit. not function typescript error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following class

```
import { ClassAsset } from './class-asset';

export class Class {
    ClassId:string;
    ClassName:string;
    Assets:ClassAsset[];

    GetAssetsString():string{
        var str:string;
        this.Assets.forEach(a=>{
            str+=a.AssetName;
        });

        return str;
    }
```

with the following angular view code

```
<tr *ngFor="let cls of classList">
        <td>{{cls.className}}</td>
        <td>{{cls.GetAssetsString()}}</td>
      </tr>
```

My Component looks like this

```
export class ClassesComponent implements OnInit {
  private _client:HttpClient;
  public classList:Class[]=[];

  constructor(client:HttpClient,private route:Router,private datasource:DataService) {
    this._client=client;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getClasses();
  }

  getClasses()
  {
    this.datasource.getClassList().subscribe((resp:Class[])=>{
      console.log(resp);
      this.classList=resp;}
      );
  }
}
```

However I get the error

> TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.GetAssetsString is not a function

What am I doing wrong? (I am still getting used to Typescript...)

Comment: Could you add definition of component to question?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Because you are **casting** the response received from server into your **Class** object. And most probably its an object that has data but not functions. This is the reason **GetAssetsString** function is not available in your code.

Having said that, you can create a constructor in your **Class** object like this

```js
export class Class {
    ClassId:string;
    ClassName:string;
    Assets:ClassAsset[];

    constructor(obj?:any){
      this.ClassId= obj && obj.ClassId || '';
      this.ClassName= obj && obj.ClassName || '';
      this.Assets = obj && obj.Assets || [];
    }

    GetAssetsString():string{
        var str:string;
        this.Assets.forEach(a=>{
            str+=a.AssetName;
        });

        return str;
    }
}
```

And your getClasses method would get modified like this

```js
          getClasses()
          {
            this.datasource.getClassList().pipe(map(response =>
            response.json())).subscribe(x=>{
              this.classList= x.map(x1=>new Class(x1));
              });
          }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I get the error "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Class[]>'"

Comment: Wrap the map operator inside pipe operator. I updated the code example, please check it. pipe is a composing function and preferred way of using operators in RxJS library.

Comment: Right, I have made the change. However this.classList ends up as a array of classes with empty properties. If I put a console.log(obj) in the class constructor it outputs a correctly populated class but if I then put console.log(obj.ClassId) it is an empty string... I do notice that for the console.log(obj) all the properties start with lowercase letters rather than uppercase...